# Show a specific non-nested div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sets of divs that I intend to use as menus. I did some Jquery code to display them, and it works fine for one but if I want to create more then I get all divs toggled. I figured maybe adding something like `data-index ="0"` to relate them would be a good approach but cant's seem to make it work

```js
menuState = {
  menuOpen: false,
  timer: false
}
$('.main, .sub').on('mouseover', () => {
  clearInterval(menuState.timer)
  if (menuState.menuOpen) { return }
  $('.sub').show();
  menuState.menuOpen = true
})

$('.main, .sub').on('mouseout', () => {
  menuState.timer = setTimeout( () => {
    menuState.menuOpen = false
    $('.sub').hide()
  }, 300)
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.thing {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thing pink main" data-index ="0">Hover</div>
<div class="thing pink sub" data-index ="0">Show</div>

<div class="thing blue main" data-index ="1">Hover</div>
<div class="thing blue sub"  data-index ="1">Show</div>
```

Just yo be sure, the expected behavior is, if I hover the blue div then another blue div would show. If I hover the pink div a pink div would show.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I really need the drop-down menu to stay since this is a simplified menu and on the toggled div there will be information for the user.

Comment: Why js and not css?

Comment: I simplify the example but in the real application is a navigation with different links and a div with all the content for the drop-down outside the navigation. I figured JS would work better for this approach.

Comment: Look at @Rory McCrossan 's answer

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for JS here as you can achieve all that logic in a single CSS rule:

```
.main:hover + .sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.thing {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
}

.main:hover + .sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thing pink main" data-index="0">Hover</div>
<div class="thing pink sub" data-index="0">Show</div>

<div class="thing blue main" data-index="1">Hover</div>
<div class="thing blue sub" data-index="1">Show</div>

<div class="thing pink main" data-index="0">Hover</div>
<div class="thing pink sub" data-index="0">Show</div>
```

Comment: If you go outside the blue hover area the drop-down disappears. And since this is for a navigation I need it to stay.

Comment: That's a fairly major logic change that's different from your original question - even if you used JS code to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main, .sub').on('mouseover', function() {
  clearInterval(menuState.timer)
  if (menuState.menuOpen) { return }
  if ($(this).hasClass('.sub')) {
    $(this).show();
  } else {
    $('.sub[data-index="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').show();
  }
  menuState.menuOpen = true
})
```

Since you haven't given us the html for classes .sub and .main I can't give a perfect answer, but what you're looking for us use of the this variable. CSS is a better choice than using js though

Comment: There is an HTML in the snippet

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake, I'll fix it

Comment: I also made an edit to explain the expected behavior. I used JS because I need the div with the sub class to stay since it will have content for the user.

Comment: Does this work for you? because for me it doesnt, maybe I'm doing something wrong? [Here](https://codepen.io/OmarAguinaga/pen/VzyBYZ) is my attempt with your code

Comment: Fixed it, I didn't notice your broken es6 syntax when I copied and pasted the original function